# Error migrating CoreData after deleted attribute from entity

Tags: swift, core-data, database-migration

My default datamodel had an attribute (sectionNumber) which I deleted from an entity (Tip). This entity did not exist in the previous datamodel.

After I recreated the mapping model I get this error (only when I test migration):

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath sectionNumber not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Tip id=3>`

I have searched everywhere in the project for sectionNumber but have not found it ... anyone know where I should look?

Comment: When did you version and exactly what is installed that you're migrating from

Comment: I created the new version months ago but I deleted the unwanted attribute today. After I did that I created the mapping model. I should add that now I get this error even when I am not migrating.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you change the model it's part of a conceptual release. At the start of this conceptual release you version the model, then you make a set of model changes and create an associated migration plan (automatic or a mapping model). When you deploy this conceptual release the migration works between the versions of the model.

If you make a change to the model after the deployment and without starting a new conceptual release - so you don't version the model - core data will see that the current model has changed but it doesn't know how. It can not recover from this and the default action is to `abort`.

You need to roll back tour change and version the model. Or, you accept that you're in the middle of a conceptual release (if possible) and delete the app before reinstalling...

Comment: What do you mean by conceptual release?

Comment: a group of changes you're going to release, or plan to release, to the app store / users.

Answer (score 0):

You can solved this problem my following below steps..:

After done changes in your core data model save it.

First print path of .sqllite core data file in appdelegate code.

Copy path and open finder.

Press Ctrl+G and paste that path. Go and delete that .sqlite file.

Now go on derived data folder path and remove everything in that folder.

Now press alt and select clean build folder option on product menu.

Now run your code and enjoy..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I am still having a problem - see above.

Comment: The comment disappeared ... it was that I am getting this error: "2015-11-13 11:53:13.377 CREW Emergency Preparedness[1345:70338] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Tip' in this model.'" This is very confusing because the entity is named Tips but in one of my earlier changes I attempted to rename it to Tip. But I have reversioned it and deleted all possible files (at least I think so) and it is referring to the old name.

Comment: can u give me some clear idea what was the problem that u faced?

Comment: The problem was that the app was still trying to access an entity with a name that didn't exist but it was partly due to the fact that I had left some incorrect fetch predicates for attributes that I had deleted from the new model. This explained the failure with sectionNumber but not the problems with incorrect entity names. However, the exceptions have stopped once I fixed the predicates.